# TimeZoneInfo which was defined by local machine not found by local machine?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble with timezones, a class I've built finds the local timezone of the user using:

```
Dim Timezone As String = TimeZoneInfo.Local.ToString
```

This is then stored in a MySQL DB.

When I pull the timezone, I compare it once again with the local timezone of the user to convert the time to the local timezone:

```
 Dim D_0 As DateTime

 Dim D_1 As DateTime

 Dim Event_Timezone As TimeZoneInfo

 Dim User_Timezone As TimeZoneInfo

 Event_Timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(U_1(5).ToString)
 User_Timezone = TimeZoneInfo.Local()

 D_0 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(U_1(i + 4), Event_Timezone, User_Timezone) 
 D_1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(U_1(i + 8), Event_Timezone, User_Timezone)
```

This returns the following error:

> The time zone ID '(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)' was not found on the local computer.

This is a confusing error because this is the timezone the local computer specified only seconds earlier. It works with nearly every other timezone. Is there a better way I should be doing this? Does anyone know why a timezone defined by the local machine is not found by the local machine seconds later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.tostring.aspx) on `TimeZoneInfo` - that doesn't give the [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx), it gives the [display name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.displayname.aspx). Often they're the same in English cultures, but they don't have to be, and usually won't be in non-English cultures.

Basically you should persist `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` instead of `TimeZoneInfo.Local.ToString()`.

(Note that using the Windows system time zone identifiers pins you down to Windows pretty heavily. You might want to *consider* using TZDB time zone information instead, e.g. via my [Noda Time project](http://nodatime.org). That's a separate decision though.)

Comment: Use TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id when I insert it to the DB you mean, continue to use FindSystemTimeZoneByID when I declare it?

Comment: @JCG: Yes. The "ByID" part is the hint that the value you're using to find the time zone should be its ID :)

Comment: Ok, the ByID worked well with most other timezones, which was the reasoning behind my question. Thanks for the help.